# Where can I download social media icons?

Tags: icon

[image: facebook icon] [image: twitter icon]

I've seem these icons on lots of sites, so I assume they are publicly available and free to use.

Does any one know who designed them, and the official site?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No attribution required icons are available in PNG format here: [**Freebie: Social Media Icons**](http://www.komodomedia.com/blog/2009/06/social-network-icon-pack/)

[image: icons]